# Wrapping window content in base window class

Tags: wpf

In an application with multiple windows which inherit from a base class - `BaseWindow`, I want to have a status bar on every window. I assume this must be done with code, as one XAML-generated class cannot inherit from another.

The XAML looks like this:

```xml
<my:BaseWindow x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:my="clr-namespace:WpfApplication1">
    <StackPanel>
        <TextBlock Text="Content" />
    </StackPanel>
</my:BaseWindow>
```

and the BaseWindow class:

```cs
public class BaseWindow : Window {
    protected override void OnContentChanged(object oldContent, object newContent) {
        var sb = new StatusBar();
        sb.Items.Add(new TextBlock {
            Text = "Status bar"
        });

        var dp = new DockPanel();
        dp.Children.Add(sb);
        DockPanel.SetDock(sb, Dock.Bottom);
        dp.Children.Add((UIElement)newContent);

        base.OnContentChanged(oldContent, dp);
    }
}
```

raises the following error: **Must disconnect specified child from current parent Visual before attaching to new parent Visual.**

How can I resolve this? Alternatively, what other techniques can I use to achieve this?

Comment: Where/when is it raising that error?

Comment: Within the call to `base.OnContentChanged`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Setting the `Content` instead of calling `base.OnContentChanged` works:

```
Content = dp;
```

However, setting the `Content` directly will call OnContentChanged, causing an infinite loop. For my needs at this point, a simple flag is sufficient:

```
private bool firstRun = true;
protected override void OnContentChanged(object oldContent, object newContent) {
    if (!firstRun) { return; }

    ...

    firstRun = false;
    Content = dp;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Instead of inheriting from the base window, you could make it a container for the "child" windows, e.g. by making them Pages and putting them into a Frame inside the base window, or by making them UserControls and using DataTemplates in order to switch between different windows.

You could also make your BaseWindow a UserControl with a ContentPresenter, and instead of inheriting from it, you could just use it as the first content element of your windows, and put whatever else they need to show inside.

Comment: I need to inherit from BaseWindow for two reasons: BaseWindow exposes other functionality (properties/methods) which should be available to every window, and because BaseWindow itself inherits from another class which provides additional functionality.

Comment: Well, in WPF and XAML, it is more common to reuse functionality through aggregation, i.e. putting it into reusable components and using those in higher level groupings, than through inheritance.

Comment: This isn't something I can change at the moment.